# Excel formula: how to SUMIF values meeting certain condition until blank cell

Tags: excel

[image]

I need to sum values in column A that meet certain criteria in column B until the next blank cell. The image (link above) shows the result I need: sums of all "A" for each three of the batches. I'm using this formula to calculate a total sum for each batch, and it works fine:

```
IF(A3="";SUM(A$1:A2)-SUM(C$1:C1);"")
```

But when I try to add SUMIF condition to this formula it doesn't work:

```
=IF(A3="";SUMIF(B:B;"A";A$1:A2)-SUM(D$1:D1);"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum if requires that the range sizes be the same.

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(B3="",SUMIF($B$2:$B2,"A",$A$2:$A2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

If the value in B in the next row is a null string then it will do the SUMIF, if not it returns a null string.

The SUMIF is being done on all the values from row 2 to the row in which the formula is being placed.  We are then subtracting the already counted values above where the formula is placed in column C to get the new sum.

[image]

Comment: Ah perfect! I forgot about the range sizes. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @loir_loir if this answered your question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.